# Why public host key still need be sent in SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY?

Tags: public-key, ssh

RFC 4251(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251) states,

[page 4]

> The protocol provides the option that the server name - host key
> association is not checked when connecting to the host for the first
> time.

[page 3]

> The client has a local database that associates each host name (as
> typed by the user) with the corresponding public host key.

RFC 4419(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4419) states,
[page 3]

> The server responds with:
>
> ```
>  byte    SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>  string  server public host key and certificates (K_S)
>  mpint   f
>  string  signature of H
> ```

My question is,
After the first time connecting, the client has got server's public host key.
Why does the server still send its host key to the client in SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY (K_S) ?

Comment: Does the server _know_ who is connecting at this stage of the handshake (don't assume static IPs)? Does the server _know_ they didn't clear their public key database for whatever random reason?

Comment: (@SEJPM) Plus the server sometimes needs to replace its key due to damage or compromise or policy (e.g. time limit) or change in standards -- like openssh deciding to quasi-prohibit DSA. Plus some servers can be reached by multiple addresses and/or names at different times or even the same time; how does it know which name(s)/address(es) the client previously used and maybe remembers? Note you don't need 4419 KEX-DHGEX to see this; 4253 sec8 has the same thing for (predefined) KEX-DH.